# Unique or different word for "challenging yet rewarding"

Tags: single-word-requests

I tend to look for words that aren't commonly used, for example, *schadenfreude* (pleasure derived by someone from another person's misfortune).

I'm looking for a word that means *challenging yet rewarding*.

Comment: From your description presumably you're looking for an adjective, could you please provide a sentence where said word would fit in.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed. Response to OP's request will vary depending on the _context_ given the specific nature - i.e. two dissimilar meanings in one. I reckon that perhaps [tag:idioms] are more appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. An idiom might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider ***worthwhile***

> being worth the time or effort spent  <sub><sup>[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worthwhile)</sup></sub>

For example if a particular hike is challenging but your are rewarded with a spectacular view from the top, you could describe the hike as being very *worthwhile* or *well worth your while*.

Answer (score 1):

*High-stakes*, though that can also refer to risk/reward rather than effort/reward.

(Few things are rewarding without being challenging, so you might also consider just dropping the "challenging" qualifier.)

Answer (score 1):

Phrases:

<sub><sup>[Collins]</sup></sub>

[Moral victory](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/moral-victory) comes to mind. Similar expressions would be: *lesson learned, moral of the story is...* (in spite of an *unfavourable* outcome or a lack of desired results).

---

Also, some adjectives and verbs to intrigue/to be used as starting points for your search:

adj.

- Fruitful
- Fulfilling
- Satisfying
- Worthwhile

v.

- Overcome
- Endeavour

**Sample sentence**: After my *endeavours* to complete the project, I was swept with an *exhilarating* sense of accomplishment.